# Android Space Bar Is Not Working

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-widget, android-softkeyboard

In my Android project I have restricted `Edittext` to allow only `Alphanumeric` characters. I have using below code snippet to achieve this

```
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edt_text"
            android:layout_width="140dp"      
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"                                   
            android:layout_margin="5dp"                                                 
            android:digits="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890"
            android:ems="10"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:maxLength="8"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:singleLine="true" />
```

But while using this code if I tab the `Space Bar` showing in `soft keypad` it is acting as a `BackSpace`button and removing the characters in `EditText`. Anyone please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I don't need a `Space` in `Edittext`

Answer (score 1):

You can also handle this Programetically.

```
mEditText1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.equals(" ")) {
                mEditText1.getText().toString().trim();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

I hope it may help you. :)

Answer (score 1):

I know it's very too late, but the problem is in the `input` digit restriction you have set.

[image: sample]

Answer (score 0):

How about allowing the spacebar to create a space, and just remove it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

use this RegEx it will return true if it is alphanumeric else it will return false.

```
public boolean isAlphaNumeric(String s){
    String pattern= "^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$";
        if(s.matches(pattern)){
            return true;
        }
        return false;   
}
```

Comment: where I need to use this, can you elaborate it?

Comment: if (isAlphaNumeric(getUserName) where getUserName is String that user entered in EditText...