# Disable SPACE key in EditText android

Tags: android, android-edittext, keyevent, keycode

I'd created EditText with following.

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_regis_num"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:digits="1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        android:hint="@string/txt_reg_num"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:maxLength="10" />
```

in this edittext I don't want to press SPACE key but when I'm pressing SPACE key it's working as BACKSPACE key. means it's deleting one character in each twice press.

Comment: Didn't get your question. Is this (space working as backspace) the current behavior or the expected behavior?

Comment: You can set input filters as like mentioned in this post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33993041/android-disable-space-only-for-edittext

Comment: @IshitaSinha agree

Comment: I have test on simulator (Nexus API 19) and it don't happend

Comment: @MujammilAhamed I tried that one also but still facing same problem.

Comment: actually when I'm pressing space button from keyboard after filling the edit =text till 10 digits. after pressing space button it's deleting one bye one character from last. working as BACKSPACE key.  @IshitaSinha

Comment: @SaunikSingh your layout seems to be fine for me no issues with that

Comment: @eLemEnt try this at your end you will get the actual problem.

Comment: @SaunikSingh You have specified `android:maxLength="10"` and `android:digits="1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"`. What is the behavior if you try pressing any key other than space after the 10-character limit? Which devices have you tried this on?

Comment: @SaunikSingh Is there any manipulation of Edittext from your activity code??

Comment: @IshitaSinha Lennovo A7000a & Xiomi MI4

Comment: and what happens if you press any key other than the space key after reaching the 10-char limit?

Comment: @sJy nothing manipulation in fragment v4 & Activity end regarding it. just as usual using setText if any value is available in variable.

Comment: @IshitaSinha nothing happen after reaching 10 alphanumeric digits.except SPACE key press

Comment: @PhanVănLinh try to test in actual device not in emulator.

Comment: @SaunikSingh in that case, try adding a space character to your `android:digits` attribute.

Comment: @IshitaSinha my requirement doesn't match this criteria. I can't allow space in this edit text.

Comment: This is the first time I encountered this and it drove me crazy. It seems like a bug in `EditText`. [Other people](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36445783/android-space-bar-is-not-working) seem to have encountered this as well, with no solution. Your best bet seems to remove `android:digits` from the xml and handle the input programmatically with a regex or something. Also, this only happens with the soft keyboard. With the hard keyboard, the `EditText` doesn't register the space key.

Answer (score 10):

Set `InputFilter` on `EditText`.
Please check below answer it's worked for me.

```
InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
        Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        for (int i = start; i < end; i++) {
            if (Character.isWhitespace(source.charAt(i))) {
                return "";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};

edtTxt.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```

Comment: This approach has very strange side effect (if suggestions are enabled for this EditText) - tapping space triggers like backspace. 1st entered space in the end of EditText really filters out, but next space tappings works like backspace erasing entered text which is totally weird. To avoid this side effect you could use inputType="textVisiblePassword" - with this workaround it will work.

Answer (score 4):

Just allow space in your edittext and replace space with empty,

```
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    String result = s.toString().replaceAll(" ", "");
    if (!s.toString().equals(result)) {
         ed.setText(result);
         ed.setSelection(result.length());
         // alert the user
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried if I already mentioned android:digits. so Space will not be consider here.

Comment: have you tried to add like this android:digits=" 1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ" in xml

Comment: I tried like this
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/et_regis_num"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:digits=" 1234567890ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
        android:hint="@string/txt_reg_num"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:maxLength="10" /> and afterTextChanged

Comment: i tried this when i press space key twice it deletes only last character

Answer (score 2):

```
   EditText editPassword = findViewById(R.id.et_Rpassword);
            editPassword.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                @Override
                public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                }
                @Override
                public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                    if(charSequence.length() > 0){
                    if((charSequence.charAt(i)+"").equalsIgnoreCase(" ")){
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "you'r can't enter Space", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        String oldPass = editPassword.getText().toString();
                        editPassword.setText(oldPass.replace(" ",""));
                    }
                }}
                @Override
                public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                }
            });
```

Comment: Code-only answers are considered low quality: make sure to provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post. See [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/)

Answer (score 1):

```
private InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {


        if(source.equals(" ")){
            int startSelection=editTextView.getSelectionStart();
            int endSelection=editTextView.getSelectionEnd();
            editTextView.setText(editTextView.getText().toString().trim());
            editTextView.setSelection(startSelection,endSelection);

        }

        return null;
    }
};

editTextView.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { filter });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    passwordEditText.filters = arrayOf(
        InputFilter { source, start, end, _, _, _ ->
            for (i in start until end) {
                if (Character.isWhitespace(source[i])) {
                    return@InputFilter ""
                }
            }
            null
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 edittxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String str = s.toString();
                if (str.equalsIgnoreCase(" ")||str.equalsIgnoreCase("  ")) {
                    // orderdata.setError("Space is not allowed");
                    edittxt.setText("");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                          int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```